# Trouble with python3 from command line vs running from Mu editor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to get my python script to run on startup (rasberri pi 4 with rasbian). It runs perfectly when I run it from the Mu editor, plays all the sounds, etc.

However when testing from the command line the script gives no errors, runs in a loop but plays no sounds when I press the buttons.

The command I run:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python3 /home/pi/whaletest2.py &
[1] 1532
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ playing sound using  pydub
```

The script I run:

```
from gpiozero import Button
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

#########################

btn1 = Button(17)

player1 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/home/pi/Whalesong/whale1.wav")
print('playing sound using  pydub')

def whale1():
    print("whale1")
    play(player1)

btn1.when_pressed = whale1

########################
btn2 = Button(27)

player2 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/home/pi/Whalesong/whale2.wav")


def whale2():
    print("whale2")
    play(player2)

btn2.when_pressed = whale2


########################
btn3 = Button(22)

player3 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/home/pi/Whalesong/whale3.wav")


def whale3():
    print("whale3")
    play(player3)

btn3.when_pressed = whale3

########################
btn4 = Button(5)

player4 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/home/pi/Whalesong/whale4.wav")


def whale4():
    print("whale4")
    play(player4)

btn4.when_pressed = whale4

########################
btn5 = Button(6)

player5 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/home/pi/Whalesong/whale5.wav")


def whale5():
    print("whale5")
    play(player5)

btn5.when_pressed = whale5
```

I have checked if the script is actually running with `ps aux | grep python` and it seems to be:

I cannot figure out what else could be going wrong here. I am hoping some more experienced programmer could help me out here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you running with `sudo`? It means you will have different environment variables from your normal user and any modules you installed using `pip --user` won't be available.

Comment: I cant give you a good reason to be honest other then it was my understanding that installing using sudo will install it for all users.